# How do I print the values of for in loop result into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

How to print the for in loop output values into an array

I have a json and filtered the most common last names and value of how many times it is repeated,

```
 public peopleData:People[]
  public surname:string
  public surnameLength:number
  public surnameArr = []
  public surnameLengthArr = []

  constructor(private pplDataService:PeopleDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pplDataService.getAllPeoplesData().subscribe(
          data => {
            this.peopleData = data
            let surnames = this.peopleData             
            let group = surnames.reduce((acc,el)=>{
              let key = (el.name.last);
              (acc[key] ? acc[key] : (acc[key] = null || [])).push(key)
              return acc   
            },{})
            for(let lastName in group){                    
              console.log([lastName,group[lastName].length])
              this.surname = lastName
              this.surnameLength = group[lastName].length
              let nameArr = this.surnameArr.push(this.surname)
              let nameArrLng = this.surnameLengthArr.push(this.surnameLength)
              console.log(nameArr)
              console.log(nameArrLng)
            }
          }
        )
  }
```

**console output**

`console.log([lastName,group[lastName].length])` this console is printing all the values

```
people-data.component.ts:65 Key 10
people-data.component.ts:65 Walls 10
people-data.component.ts:65 Booker 10
people-data.component.ts:65 Salazar 10
people-data.component.ts:65 Merritt 10
people-data.component.ts:65 Harrell 10
people-data.component.ts:65 Sharp 10
people-data.component.ts:65 Hammond 10
people-data.component.ts:65 Chan 10
```

**console output**

When I tried pushing lastName and its length it is not printing an array with values

```
people-data.component.ts:70 1
people-data.component.ts:71 1
people-data.component.ts:70 2
people-data.component.ts:71 2
people-data.component.ts:70 3
people-data.component.ts:71 3
people-data.component.ts:70 4
people-data.component.ts:71 4
people-data.component.ts:70 5
people-data.component.ts:71 5
people-data.component.ts:70 6
people-data.component.ts:71 6
people-data.component.ts:70 7
people-data.component.ts:71 7
people-data.component.ts:70 8
people-data.component.ts:71 8
people-data.component.ts:70 9
people-data.component.ts:71 9
```

I want to print the values like

```
surNameArr = ["Key","Walls","Booker","Salazar","Merritt","Harrell","Sharp","Hammond","Chan"]
surnameLengthArr = [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]
```

Comment: have you read the [MDN docs for Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Description)?

Comment: "I have a json": actually, no, you don't. You have a JavaScript array. JSON is a text format.

Comment: @trincot it's a long thankless struggle, but on the bright side there are only 7 billion people in the world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resulting values when you call `push()` are the new lengths of the arrays.

So, when your `nameArr = ["Key","Walls"]`, it already contains two values, and the next time you call `nameArr.push("Booker")` it will return **3**, as this is the new length of the array.

If you want to print your expected arrays, you should simply populate them in the for loop, and print your values after it:

```
for(let lastName in group){                    
    console.log([lastName,group[lastName].length])
    this.surname = lastName
    this.surnameLength = group[lastName].length
    this.surnameArr.push(this.surname)
    this.surnameLengthArr.push(this.surnameLength)
}

// print out populated arrays
console.log(this.surnameArr)
console.log(this.surnameLengthArr)
```